# How can we disprove that formally?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove $2^{A\times B}=\{A'\times B'\mid A'\subseteq A, B'\subseteq B\}$.

$2^{A\times B}=\text{ set of every subset of } A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.

So it is of the form $2^{A\times B}=\{\emptyset, \{(a_i, b_i)\}, \{(a_i, b_i), (a_j, b_j)\}, \cdots \}$, or not?

This is not of the form $\{A'\times B'\mid A'\subseteq A, B'\subseteq B\}$, is it?

But how can we disprove that formally?

Comment: I think $2^{A\times B}$ is a bad notation, as it can also mean the set of all functions from $A\times B$ and $2=\{0,1\}$ (although they are isomorphic.)

Comment: $2^{A\times B}$ is the powerset of $A\times B$. @HanulJeon

Comment: I know, I just want to say your notation is not recommended.

Comment: Ahh ok! Do you have an idea about that? @HanulJeon

Comment: The standard notation, widely used by set theorists, is $P(A\times B)$.

Comment: Ahh ok! Is my idea correct that we have to disprove the statement $P(A\times B)=\{A'\times B'\mid A'\subseteq A, B'\subseteq B\}$ ? @HanulJeon

Comment: Your idea is ambiguous to understand for me; in fact, your statement holds if either $A$ or $B$ is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the right idea: namely that it is not of the form $\{A' \times B' : A' \subseteq A, B' \subseteq B\}$. To prove this you just need to come up with a counterexample.

A nice counterexample would be to take $A = B = \mathbb{R}$. That way we can get a very geometric interpretation of $A \times B$: it is just the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\{A' \times B' : A', B' \subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$ describes the set of all (unions of) rectangles (where I count a line as an infinitely thin rectangle). Can you now think of an element of $P(A \times B)$ (i.e. a subset of the plane) that is not in $\{A' \times B' : A', B' \subseteq \mathbb{R}\}$?

Answer (score 0):

If one of $A$ or $B$ is a singleton or the empty set, then your statement is true. However, it is false if $|A|,|B|\ge 2$.

The simplest example would be $A\times B \setminus \{(a,b)\}$ for some $(a,b)\in A\times B$: You can see that if $A_0\times B_0\subseteq A\times B \setminus \{(a,b)\}$ then either $A_0\neq A$ or $B_0\neq B$.

If $A_0\neq A$, so we have $a_0$ such that $a_0\in A\setminus A_0$, then $(a_0,y)\notin A_0\times B_0$ for *all* $y\in B$. However, we have $(a_0,b_0)\in A\times B\setminus\{(a,b)\}$ for all $b_0\in B\setminus\{b\}$. Therefore $A_0\times B_0\neq A\times B \setminus \{(a,b)\}$. The similar argument also works for the case $B_0\neq B$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you want to disprove is:

"For $every$ $A$ and $every$ $B,\; 2^{A\times B}=\{A'\times B':A'\subset A\land B'\subset B\}.$"

So you want to prove:

There exist $A$ and $B$ such that $2^{A\times B}\ne \{A'\times B':A'\subset A\land B'\subset B\}.$

To prove that, it suffices to present just one instance of such $A,B.$

Suppose $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2\},$ with $a_1\ne a_2$ and $b_1\ne b_2.$  Let $C= \{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\}.$ Then $C\in 2^{A\times B}.$

But $C\ne A'\times B'$ for $any$ $A',B'.$ Because if $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ belong to $A'\times B',$ then $a_1\in A'$ and $b_2\in B',$ so $(a_1,b_2)\in A'\times B'$.... but $(a_1,b_2)\not \in C.$